# Radeon HD + vgaswitcheroo

Tags: graphics, radeon, hybrid-graphics, vgaswitcheroo

I have a Hp Envy4 1025tx machine. I've tried vgaswitcheroo and amdcccle. I'm happy with Vgaswitcheroo powersaving efficiency and amdcccle's performance. I want both of them on my system. Is there a way to configure a kernel to boot into either one of these settings from the grub boot menu.

I mostly dont need discreet graphic card. But when I need it, I use it at the extremes. Please help me with the procedure.